# Laravel validation for two column with same value exist on table

Tags: laravel, validation

The actual scenario is  i have to check if two same column value exist on table or not 
For example first I input  `user_id = 1` and `rv_id = 2`

I should not store same sequence value again `(user_id = 1 and rv_id = 2)` 
but I can store  `user_id = 1 and rv_id = 3` or `user_id =1 and rv_id =1`

```
$request->validate([

            'rv_id'     => 'required|unique:favorite_unites,rv_id,user_id|exists:rvs,id', 
            'user_id'   => 'required|unique:favorite_unites,user_id,rv_id|exists:users,id',

        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case i guess you need to create a custom Rule

**Request class :**

```
// Read more in bottom
'name' => ['required', new MustMatchCustomValue('rv_id')],
```

**Rule class (use artisan to create it)**

```
class ValidateTwoValues implements Rule
{
    protected $rvId;

    public function __construct($rvId)
    {
        $this->rvId = $rvId;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        // $value contains the user_id
        // $this->rvId contains the other value
        // Do DB check here using DB::table('')...etc

        // return true if it's okay, or false if not
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'You already have the selected RV.';
    }
}
```

**NOTE :** I'm Note sure if passing the attribute string as a param to the Rule class will actually send the value or just the string, In case it's just a string you have to swap it by `new MustMatchCustomValue($this->rv_id)`

Answer (score 0):

You were actually on the right track, you had just one simple mistake. Change `exists:rvs,id` to `exists:rvs` and exists:users,id to `exists:users` (if those are your table names). You need to pass `table_name` instead of `column` in that validation rule. From official documentation:

> exists:table,column
>
> The field under validation must exist on a given database table.

Read more about validation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation).